# Python/Django date field in html input tag

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to display a date in an input field as so:

```
<tr><td>Date of Birth</td><td><input type="date" name="DOB" value="{{m.dob|date:"d/m/Y"}}" required=True></td></tr>
```

where m.dob is defined in the model as:

```
dob = models.DateField('Date of Birth', blank=True, null=True)
```

The HTML input tag shows the date as dd/mm/yyyy when the page is loaded but I can see the field has taken the value assigned.  How do I get it to display correctly?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `value="{{m.dob|date:'d/m/Y'}}"` which must be specified as `value="{{m.dob|date:'Y-m-d'}}"`

Answer (score 1):

Dude, your question is not clear. But for now, I am assuming you are new to Django.

Your DB value is not populating in the template. In order to show the value, you must do two steps:

- First query the model object
- Pass it through additional context dictionary from the Django view.

```py
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render

class Home(View):
    template_name = "home.html"
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        pass

    def get(self, request):
        # Fetch your object here. ID or any other 
        myObj = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
        # Third argument is the conext dictionary
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'myObj': myObj})
```

Now just use that `myObj` in your template with the following syntax.

```
<tr><td>Date of Birth</td><td><input type="date" name="DOB" value="{{myObj.dob|date:"d/m/Y"}}" required=True></td></tr>
```

Here this code is in **home.html**.

Comment: I'm doing all that and yet my input field is not showing the value I'm passing.   I can see the value is being passed because if I inspect the object I can see chrome has it in the background in the right format but it is not displaying it in the html date field

Answer (score 1):

If using ModelForm and passing that form object to template, then it should be

```
value="{{m.dob.value|date:'Y-m-d'}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `default` like so:

```
date = models.DateField(_("Date"), default="{{"+datetime.date.today+"}}")
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't explained my question well.  How do I get it to show up in an HTML `<input type="date" value="{{mydate}}">`?

Comment: how about that ? I guess you are doing this for js manipulation purposes ?!

Answer (score 0):

You can just add

```
`<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("id_dob").type = "date";
    }
</script>`
```

in the end of your .html file and you can collect date and time as string

Comment: This is probably not the best practice.